# How to match each occurrence per line?

Tags: regular-expression, delimiter-matching

I have similar text on more lines:

`_AB_ _ABC_ _` *OR* `_ _A_ _ABC_`

I need to replace only the underscores that delimit some text. So I need:

`=AB= =ABC= _` *OR* `_ =A= =ABC=`

How to match each pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
%s/_\([A-Za-z]\+\)_/=\1=/g
```

Where

- `[A-Za-z]` matches the chars A-Z and a-z. You could add other chars between `[]`. Note: If you want to add a dash (`-`), it has to be the first char after the opening `[`.
- `\+` means "one or more".

Comment: Note that you can replace `[A-Za-z]` with `\a`  (or you could use `\w` to add [0-9]` too). See [`:h /character-classes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fcharacter-classes)

Comment: @statox I knew `\w`, but that would also add the underscore. But `\a` is good (and I didn't knew it :-)).

Comment: If you're looking for single-token representations of those don't forget the POSIX style character classes _[:alpha:]_ and _[:alnum:]_ e.g. `/[[:alnum:]]`. (Or do forget them...they're not particularly short and they're ASCII only. :)